# how to add the button onto the mc mod without errors?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, minecraft, forge

I want to create a 1.19 forge Minecraft Mod that shows a button with custom text when the Furnace GUI is open, but the problem is that i can't get it to work! I also tried asking ChatGPT and Copilot, but still doesn't work. I haven't found tutorials on youtube, so can please someone post a code and clear instructions on how to use the code? (i'm using forge 39.0.5 for mc 1.19,java 17.0.1 and Intellij Idea as java IDE)

Comment: First of all, don't use AI. It may generate usable code in some cases, but Minecraft Modding isn't one of them, especially given how many different modloaders and mappings. AI will take many snippets, all from different loaders and mappings and hodge-podge them all together, even if you tell it to do it for specific loaders and mappings (it just can't tell). Secondly, you can't simply add gui components to existing GUIs (as far as I'm aware, maybe there's an event but I doubt it), you may need to look into [Mixins](https://github.com/SpongePowered/Mixin/wiki/Mixins-on-Minecraft-Forge).

Comment: Can you please post the code you made here?

Comment: I only used ai code, and i saw many mods that add gui components to existing gui, so there is a way

Comment: can you help me with mixin?

Comment: Mixins basically allow you to indirectly modify vanilla code. See [this link](https://github.com/SpongePowered/Mixin/wiki/Mixins-on-Minecraft-Forge) that I put into the first comment. Follow the instructions there.

Comment: mixin supports 1.19?

Comment: Mixin works with all *Minecraft* versions (but on Forge is more difficult to add pre-1.14). However, Mixin doesn't work in *Java 19+* (which is nothing to worry about; hundreds of the biggest mods still use Mixin).

Comment: can you help me with a fabric 1.19 mod that adds a custom GUI component(button) to the furnace GUI?

Comment: What does the button do?

Comment: Nothing, i will think of it later, i just want a button with custom editabile text in the fornace GUI

Comment: Why are you adding something if you don't know what it will do!?! Will it be clientside or will it need to modify the furnace data in any way?

Comment: Will do server-sided changes, that i will implement, dont worry i just need help creating the button, but when pressed the changes (that i will implement in future) mustang be server sided

Comment: This conversation is starting to become way too long. There are plenty of Discord servers that can help you (such as [The Fabric Project](https://discord.gg/v6v4pMv) or [The NeoForged Project](https://discord.gg/UvedJ9m)). You can ask for help there. Someone can help you better there than I can here.

Comment: Ok the mod should be able to server side dupe items on minecraft and i wondered if you could help me create a button in the fornace GUI that dupes the item in the inferior fornace slot in the superior slot

Comment: Again, please ask on Discord or elsewhere (like [Forge Forums](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/)). This is too complex for a single-line stackexchange comment thread.